# Laravel 5.3 : eager load with many to many relationship

Tags: eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to use eloquent to retrieve 5 last messages and display them on the dashboard.

The problem is, I need to get those messages depending on the user->role. But the message is linked to an update log. This update log is use to dispatch every dashboard message, sms to notify and email.

There is how it work :

User

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

Role

```
public function updatelogs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Updatelog::class, 'role_updatelog');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Updatelog

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_updatelog');
}

public function dashboard_message()
{
    return $this->hasOne(DashboardMessage::class);
}
```

DashboardMessage

```
public function updatelog()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Updatelog::class);
}
```

There is what I tried:

```
    $dashmessages = DashboardMessage::with(array('updatelog' => function($q) use($user) {
        $q->with(array('roles' => function($q2) use($user) {
            $q2->whereHas($user->role_id);
        }));
        $q->whereHas('institution');
    }))->with('updatelog.institution.rate_grids')->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
```

I'm getting the last 5 DashboardMessages without the role constraint. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT---------------------------------------------------**
I just tried something else and it work perfectly:

```
$updatelog = Updatelog::whereHas('roles', function ($query) use($user) {
                            $query->where('role_id', $user->role_id);
                        })
                        ->whereHas('dashboard_message')
                        ->with('dashboard_message')
                        ->whereHas('institution')
                        ->with('institution')
                        ->with('rate_grid')
                        ->take(5)->get();
```